What are these white spots/blemishes on my LED Monitor
After about an year I took out my LED monitor (Samsung s20b300). It shows some random white spots on the corner and in the center.
Is there something wront with monitor or it can be some problem with the VGA cable? I'm using VGA to HDMI converter because my laptop only has HDMI ports.


could be the desktop graphic ... unplug the VGA cable ... do the spots remain?

Yes the spots are still visible

What could have caused this problem? and Is there some way to solve this problem?

maybe they are scuff marks ... do you see them when power is turned off?

the screen is clear when turned off....Initially I also had the same thought, so I cleaned it with a micro fiber cloth yet marks remain

There are applications such as IsMyLcdOK, https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/IsMyLcdOK, that have a small chance to help by "exercising" pixels. Though it's not likely to work, it's free, and requires no installation. Please let me know if it does help, though. BTW, storage of LCD in very hot, extremely cold, or damp conditions can cause that issue.
